# Install Druid on AWS EMR

Tags: hadoop, amazon-emr, druid

Just started exploring Druid we dint find any blog on link to install Druid on AWS, Is there any chance to install Druid on AWS EMR ? If so if there are any per-defined Cloud Formation to execute it will be help full for my R&D on Druid.

Answer (score 2):

its pretty straighforward to setup a basic single cluster druid

- launch EMR with a single node master, like r3.4xlarge
- download imply tar (comes with druid and pivot), https://docs.imply.io/on-prem/quickstart

```
tar -xzf imply-3.1.8.1.tar.gz cd imply-3.1.8.1
bin/supervise -c conf/supervise/quickstart.conf
```

If you are looking for a full cluster deploy, EMR is not the right tool. 
If you know EKS / kubernetes, I think the easiest way to get started is using Helm
https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/druid

Other option is to look for Imply Cloud
They also solid documentation around Druid. Druid'd own documentation is pretty intense. I found imply to be better for beginners.
https://docs.imply.io/cloud/

Although for POC, a single r3.4xlarge or i3.4xlarge having some 200G storage is good enough

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason why you would not find much documentation is that the two things have a different nature.

Druid is meant to be long lived and statefull, where the EMR hadoop variant is meant to spin up and down in a more ephemeral manner. As such the combination is somewhat awkward.

Consider using a different hadoop distribution like HDP. Of course you can easily deploy it on AWS if needed, or on your own hardware if you want to minimize infra costs.

Disclaimer: I am an employee of Cloudera, the distributor of HDP, which is currently the most common hadoop platform  under Druid.